# React: How to make store invulnerable for reload?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, store, use-context, use-reducer

I created store with `useReducer`, and provide state and `dispatch` function by `Context` provider:

```
/*code...*/
import { InsuranceItemContext } from './Context/InsuranceItemContext';
import { reducer } from './Reducer/Reducer';

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, undefined);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <InsuranceItemContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
        <div className='App'>
          <Header />
          <Section />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </InsuranceItemContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the next file, I receive data and transfer it to the store by `dispatch` function:

```
/*some code...*/
<input onClick={() => dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_ITEM',
        payload: {
            coverage: coverageValue,
            risk: props.risk,
            price,
            title: props.title
        }
    })} type='submit' name='submit' className='submit' />
/*some code...*/
```

Each component of my app works correctly but I have one trouble: my store's data vanish each time I reload a page or render another component. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: You can look - redux-persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose, I should use `localStorage`. Because It saves data on the user device (browser).
So, If I want to record some data to `localStorage` I have to use these instructions:

```
 localStorage.setItem() //for recording
 localStorage.getItem() //for reading
```

My main mistake was recording data without `JSON.stringify()` function, because `localStorage` transform my data into `string` (in my case it was an object and the result was `[object Object]`).

All in all, I got it, and changed my code to the variant:

```
 localStorage.setItem('variable', JSON.stringify(variable)) //for recording
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('variable')) //for reading
```

`JSON.parse()` I use for decrypting json notation and receive data in original view.
So, here my changes:

```
/*some code*/ 
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state) localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type:'GET_DATA', payload: 
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))});
  }, []);
  console.log('Local storage: ' + JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.state));
  console.log('My storage: ' + JSON.stringify(state));
}
/*some code*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `Redux` is a global state manager that keeps the state in session. If you reload the page, new session starts and everything stored in redux disappears.

If you want a persistent global state manager you should use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) that is a combination of `redux` and `localStorage` (as default for web, but you should select a different storage).